# Getting an object reference not set error when im sure it is set

Tags: c#

I am getting an 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error and i cannot workout why as i am declaring and creating the object globally.

The exception is firing when i try to add the first item to a dictionary.  Heres my code:

```
//declared at the top of my page globally
Dictionary <String, MyCustomType> MyDictionary = new Dictionary();
MyCustomType myCustomType = new MyCustomType();

//Then later in a (private void) method:
//First part of if statement checks if we already have anything in there 
//and if the key already exists. If so, it overwrites it

if (MyDictionary != null && MyDictionary.ContainsKey(some_string)
{
    //  replace the item in the dictionary
}
// if the dictionary is null or the key isnt already in the dictionary.  
// This is where it is throwing the exception
else 
{
    MyDictionary.add(some_string, myCustomType)
}
```

When debugging through, it does say the MyDictionary is null, but this is to be expected as i have nothing in there yet, and the act off the add in the else statement puts something in there, so im really not sure why its throwing an exception here.  The debug also shows that some_string and myCustomType has the values i expect them to have.   Can anyone help?

Comment: As you own comment states _**if the dictionary is null** or the key isnt already in the dictionary_ then add key value

Comment: Yeah - but that is where it is throwing the exception.  When i try to add the item

Comment: You code contains errors (e.g. `new Dictionary()`, non-matching curly braces). It would not compile.

Comment: @Ricardinho yes, because it will go to else part also if `MyDictionary` is null and there you just add an item without checking if it's null

Comment: It's a logic problem... if MyDictionary is null then you fall to the else, and try adding to a null dictionary.

Comment: try to replace your `new Dictionary()` with `new Dictionary<string, MyCustomType>()`

Comment: Thanks all for the comments.  Got a lot to go on here! :)

Comment: it's a good practice to define collections as readonly fields when possible, e.g: `private readonly Dictionary <String, MyCustomType> MyDictionary = new Dictionary();`

you won't be able to set it to null, but you will find out, that you don't need to.

Comment: This could have been closed as a duplicate as it was a simple case of assuming something wasn't null when it clearly was. Program logic changes, but the problem doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
if (MyDictionary == null) MyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, CustomType>();
MyDictionary[some_string] = myCustomType;
```

Comment: Thanks - im going to rework my code to always assign to a dictionary this way

Comment: Even better solution would be to declare MyDictionary as readonly field, so it will never be null. than you dont need to do null check.

Comment: FYI - this method worked.  I still have no idea how/why/where my dictionary is being set to null, but it is somewhere and this at least caters for that scenario

Comment: just a tip for you: To find out, where your dictionary is being set to null, convert the field to property with backing field and add breakpoint to setter. breakpoint will be hit anytime somebody is trying to set the value and you can see it in callstack window

Answer (score 2):

Even if you are sure that you have no null references, there must be one; otherwise you would not get a `NullReferenceException`. The runtime is usually correct about this.

- Have you made sure that the code initializing `myDictionary` runs *at all*?
- Have you ensured that the initialization of `myDictionary` always runs *before* your private method that uses it?

---

Now on to something else:

```
myDictionary[key] = value;
```

will work in both cases, i.e. when the dictionary does not yet have an entry for `key`, but also when there is already an entry for `key`.

Using `[]` has the advantage over your current two-step process (first check using `ContainsKey`, then `Add` or update) of being more atomic; there is less risk of another thread interfering with your dictionary between the two steps. (Though, truth be told, if that is an issue at all, you might be better off using `ConcurrentDictionary`.)

Comment: It could be null if he's setting it to null somewhere

Comment: Thanks @stakx - im going to update my approach to always use MyDictionar[key] = value

Answer (score 1):

You need to test if `MyDictionary` is null and instantiate it if it is, before calling `MyDictionary.add(...`

The line:

```
Dictionary <String, MyCustomType> MyDictionary = new Dictionary();
```

won't compile, so I'm not sure what you really have in your code.

You'll need to change the code to something like:

```
if (MyDictionary != null && MyDictionary.ContainsKey(some_string)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    if (MyDictionary == null)
    {
        MyDictionary = new Dictionary<String, MyCustomType>(); 
    }
    MyDictionary.Add(some_string, myCustomType);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remake your if like this

```
if (MyDictionary != null)
{
    if(MyDictionary.ContainsKey(some_string)
    {
        //  replace the item in the dictionary
    }
     // if the dictionary is null or the key isnt already in the dictionary.      This is where it is throwing the exception
    else 
    {
        MyDictionary.add(some_string, myCustomType)
    }
}
```